# upload video on telegram bot using c#?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I want to upload a video on a telegram bot using c#. i have tried the one API for sending videos but i couldn't upload anything using this method.
is there any limits for video uploading in bots ? please any one tell me where is my mistake.and duration is necessary to pass in the API but how can i get the video duration ? i have first downloaded the video from url using web client and then i convert it in to stream and send on bot.

here is my code =>

```
byte[] videoDate;
using (var wc = new WebClient())
videoDate = wc.DownloadData(videoUrl);

var response = await
_api.SendVideo(update.Message.Chat.Id,new FileToSend(videoUrl, new MemoryStream(videoDate)), 15, myBotAdMsg);
```

here i have pass 15 duration fi right now but here my video duration is 00:10 second so how can also fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try like this =>

```
Bot.SendVideoAsync(update.Message.Chat.Id, video: VideoUrl, caption: myBotAdMsg);
```